# Unexpected behaviour with custom ListView adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, user-interface

So I've got a listView and each item basically displays 3 TextView-s one of the TextView-s represents username and if the username is equal to the logged user the item shall be highlighted(see code)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HallOfFame.User> {

private int resourceLayout;
private Context mContext;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<HallOfFame.User> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.resourceLayout = resource;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = vi.inflate(resourceLayout, null);
    }

    HallOfFame.User user = getItem(position);

    if (user != null) {
        TextView rankText = v.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        TextView usernameText = v.findViewById(R.id.username);
        TextView scoreText = v.findViewById(R.id.score);

        rankText.setText(Integer.toString(user.rank));
        usernameText.setText(user.username);
        scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(user.overall));

        if(Utils.USERNAME.equals(user.username)){
            usernameText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }

    return v;
}
}
```

[image]

In this example only MikiThenics should be highlighted. Adding else after if(Utils.USERNAME.eq...) will stop the other usernames from being highlighted but there's still this weird shift with the number on the right. And the items that are "not working" aren't always the same.

This is how the HallOfFame.User looks:

```
public class User{
    public String username;
    public int pullups=0,pushups,dips,handstandpushups,plank,pistolsquats,muscleups;
    public int overall;
    public int rank = 0;
    public User(String data,int i){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            username = jsonObject.getString(Utils.S_USERNAME);
            pullups = jsonObject.getInt(Utils.S_PULL_UPS);
            pushups = jsonObject.getInt(Utils.S_PUSH_UPS);
            dips = jsonObject.getInt(Utils.S_DIPS);
            handstandpushups = jsonObject.getInt(Utils.S_HANDSTAND_PUSHUPS);
            plank = jsonObject.getInt(Utils.S_PLANK);
            pistolsquats = jsonObject.getInt(Utils.S_PISTOL_SQUATS);
            muscleups = jsonObject.getInt(Utils.S_MUSCLE_UPS);
            overall = pullups+pushups+dips+handstandpushups+pistolsquats+muscleups+plank/60;

            rank = i;
            if(username.equals(Utils.USERNAME))
                yourPosition = i;
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

This is the example of the JSON I'm using

```
        String tmp =  "[{\"username\":\"MikiThenics\",\"pullups\":\"25\",\"pushups\":\"70\",\"dips\":\"30\",\"handstandpushups\":\"16\",\"muscleups\":\"8\",\"pistolsquats\":\"1\",\"plank\":\"360\"},{\"username\":\"user01\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user02\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user0\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user1\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user2\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user3\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user4\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user5\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user6\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user7\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user8\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user9\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user10\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user11\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user12\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user13\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user14\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user15\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user16\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user17\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user18\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user19\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user20\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user21\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user22\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user23\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user24\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user25\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user26\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user27\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user28\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user29\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user30\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user31\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user32\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user33\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user34\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user35\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user36\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user37\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user38\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user39\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user40\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user41\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user42\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user43\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user44\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user45\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user46\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user47\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user48\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user49\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user50\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user51\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user52\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user53\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user54\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user55\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user56\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user57\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user58\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user59\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user60\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user61\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user62\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user63\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user64\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user65\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user66\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user67\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user68\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user69\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user70\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user71\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user72\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user73\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user74\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user75\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user76\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"},{\"username\":\"user77\",\"pullups\":\"0\",\"pushups\":\"0\",\"dips\":\"0\",\"handstandpushups\":\"0\",\"muscleups\":\"0\",\"pistolsquats\":\"0\",\"plank\":\"0\"}]";
```

The problem is caused by the username. Since setting username in User to fixed String solves the problem.
Even though I'm using fixed string as JSON the "not working items" aren't the same when restarting the activity.

Comment: add else block. `else{  usernameText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);  }`

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that adding else helps but the weird shift on the right remains

Comment: `scoreText.setText(String.valuesof(user.overall));`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Still nothing the problem is caused by the username, as using fixed string for the username "fixes" the problem weird is that even using fixed json string results in different  broken items after restarting the activity

Comment: Solved this yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No :(

Comment: Sure thing, thanks

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya link to the sample https://github.com/Lukflyl/sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a XML issue. You can try with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="RANK"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rank"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="SCORE"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:textColorLink="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I dunno why still some of them are red, but the shift is gone and siplme else will do. Thank you ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can add an boolean into your if statement that at first it is true and when tries to highlited the username's text , set the boolean false

```
if(Utils.USERNAME.equals(user.username) && boolean){
            usernameText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
```

Comment: Yeah or I can siply use else but the weird shift with the number on the left still remains